# Float Issue: Need the image to reflect on the exact right of the text using HTML, and avoid the extra space

Tags: html

> Here is the Code Snippet:
>       Using this code, I want the image to reflect on the exact right of the text,
>       but space is getting added in the middle. I am new in HTML.Please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p><img src="smiley.jpg" alt="Smiley face" style="float:right;width:42px;height:42px;">
The image will float to the right of the text.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `<img>` tag after text and remove `float:right;` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>The image will float to the right of the text. 
    <img src="smiley.jpg"  alt="Smiley face" style="width:42px;height:42px;"> 
</p>
</body>
```